# update failed because of GPG errors

Tags: 12.04, updates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix missing GPG keys Ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys-ubuntu-12-04)

I tried to update via terminal by using the command

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and the following error pops up

```
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 2EA8F35793D8809A
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 175B884292C4BEFD Launchpad PPA for GNOME Split
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 3BDAAC08614C4B38 Launchpad otto06217
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 8CD60EC948894010 Launchpad PPA for Scopes Packagers
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 464AD83D4631BBEA Launchpad equinoxart
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 6AF0E1940624A220 Launchpad PPA for TualatriX
W: GPG error: http://archive.getdeb.net precise-getdeb Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A8A515F046D7E7CF GetDeb Archive Automatic Signing Key <archive@getdeb.net>
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

how to prevent the following errors?
I am running Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: glad to hear that. You should post this as an answer and accept it. it will help others :)