# Getting Error with sudo apt-get update?

Tags: 12.04, updates

As I go into terminal with Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit. I type in `sudo apt-get update. I enter in the required password. The termianl with process the request toward checking if there are any updates! As it get's down to the final conclusion of how long it took to process, I get this error. Here is a picture of the error!

[image]

I don't understand the error! I don't have a W: drive! I have seen this error with many users, but I can not fix this error! If you have a good fix for this error, I would appericate the advice and solution! Thanks

Comment: Try to do
`sudo apt-get clean`

Comment: take a look at here you maybe find the answer in here http://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys

Comment: `W:` stands for `Warning:`. Linux doesn't have the concept of the `C:` drive, `D:` drive, etc.

Comment: @saiarcot895 +1 for w:

Answer (score 1):

Try with following commands:

```
sudo aptitude -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True -o Acquire::BrokenProxy=true update

sudo apt-get update
```