# Unable to connect and GPG Error on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: updates, ppa, gnupg

I have been getting the following error when i apt-get update

```
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty InRelease                         
Err http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release.gpg          Unable to
connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http: Fetched 1,508 kB in 2min 5s (12.0
kB/s) Reading package lists... Done W: GPG error:
http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures
couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
NO_PUBKEY 78414460095F1873 W: Failed to fetch
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch
http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to
connect to extras.ubuntu.com:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old
ones used instead.
```

I have no idea of how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this problem by installing a software called Y PPA Manager.
copy and paste these commands in terminal to download and install it:

1. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager`

after this launch it from dash. after launching it, seach for option called "Advanced" then click on "Try to import all missing GPG keys". Then wait for sometime until you get notification that its done.
after this click on "Try to fix all GPG BADSIG error". Wait for sometime until you get notification that its done.
then try to update, you wont get any error. comment if you have any issue

Answer (score 0):

Without using any external tools (except of course [Google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=missing%20gpg%20keys)) you can do this. A solution is mentioned in [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys) Adding a GPG key is easy. You need the ID of the pubkey that's missing, and it's displayed in the error message you get. In your case, the ID is 78414460095F1873. You can fix the error by doing

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2EA8F35793D8809A
```

Comment: Before posting my question here i had already done the research and tried the above method, even by using :80 as port. but it did not work.