# update cannot be done by update manager

Tags: 12.04

I am a new Ubuntu user.12.04(32 bit ) version.I not update Ubuntu for 1 month. Now when I want to update using terminal `sudo apt-get update` then shows that:

```
reading package list done.....
:GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
W: GPG error: http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

And when I want to update using update manager then shows the massage that:

```
The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Requires installation of untrusted packages?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages)

Comment: You could generate your list file using this tool [here](http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the easiest way to resolve apt-get BADSIG GPG errors?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/1877/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-resolve-apt-get-badsig-gpg-errors)

Answer (score 0):

run these commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The first command downloads key `40976EAF437D05B5` from `keyserver.ubuntu.com`, and the next one updates your package list, then applies the needed updates.

Comment: update can be done using "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5"
"sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade"...@edward torvalds               but when i want to install softwares from ubuntu software center the massage shows that "The action would require the installation of packages from not authenticated sources." Now how can i install softwares???

Comment: @m.bhandari try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/184117/requires-installation-of-untrusted-packages?lq=1 also if you can install software you can try this: http://askubuntu.com/a/545052/294611