# Signatures not verified

Tags: 14.04, apt, ppa, gnupg, signature

These are the signature errors that persist after I tried several fixes mentioned on the Internet

```
W: GPG error: http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 517590D9A8492E35
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: GPG error: http://linux.dropbox.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY FC918B335044912E
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://dl.google.com stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A040830F7FAC5991
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net raring Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99
W: GPG error: http://archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 0CC3AFF5CEDF0F40
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 32B18A1260D8DA0B
```

I have been beating around the bush for solutions but nothing has worked yet please suggest something that would solve these errors.

What I've already tried:

1. y-ppa-manager
2. manually removing list and regenerating it.

So please don't mark duplicate for these methods and suggest something else.

Comment: are you using sudo? sudo apt-get install instead of apt-get install
?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After coming to know that apt can't handle more than 40 keys I started deleting ppa's and their keys from /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d

After doing that I updated apt-cache and my problems were solved.

Comment: Cleaning the directory indeed fixed this for me, what a strange limitation.

Comment: Strange indeed, don't know why

Comment: How did you update **apt-cache**?

Comment: I have forgotten how I did it then, but you can try cleaning the cache `sudo apt-get clean` and updating it `sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 14):

Something's gone wrong with your apt keys or adding/changing repos or something... I don't know what

- What did you do that caused these errors, and what fixes have you tried?

But here are some band-aid solutions for your symptoms:

---

To just **add the missing keys**, this command should work (replace the "2EA8..." string with your acutal missing keys)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 2EA8F35793D8809A
```

May try `--keyserver keys.gnupg.net` if any aren't on ubuntu
[see https://askubuntu.com/a/141088/129271 ]

---

It looked kind of like you didn't **add some PPA's correctly**, according to Ubuntu's instructions it should "fetch the PPA's key" by itself. Here's the terminal directions from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

> Step 2: Open a terminal and enter:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name
```

> Replace 'ppa:user/ppa-name' with the PPA's location that you noted above.
>
> Your system will now fetch the PPA's key. This enables your Ubuntu system to verify that the packages in the PPA have not been interfered with since they were built.

---

In case there's a **problem with your software sources, this should restore them to their "defaults".** I'd make a backup copy of everything in `/ect/apt/sources.list` and `/ect/apt/sources.list.d/` first, just in case. Not knowing what your Ubuntu version is I'm not sure what the "defaults" should be, or whether you've added extra PPA's or other sources. Running `lsb_release -a` should tell you about your version & "codename"

### Backup the sources.list files

Just copy them to a backup folder somewhere, this should work:

`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.old`
`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d /etc/apt/sources.list.d.old`

### Restoring the default Ubuntu `sources.list`

- For Ubuntu, if you do this it should generate a new fresh `sources.list` file

  1. delete the old files (`sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list` and `sudo rm -R /etc/apt/sources.list.d` but **BACKUP FIRST**).
  2. Then do either of:

     - Run the Software Sources (`sudo software-properties-gtk` or `sudo software-sources`) select/check-mark some repos, pick a server and update.
     - Generate a new one at http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ using your version & country (to pick local mirrors), then copy & paste it into your new sources.list with `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` or in a terminal `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

The site http://repogen.simplylinux.ch/ has a LOT of optional PPA's too, looks quite useful.  [courtesy [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) ]

Comment: even if that is correct what about the ppas that come with ubuntu pre-installed I have not added them nor disturbed them, how come they are not verifiable

Comment: I have tried y-ppa-manager and also removing the entire list and generating it again by apt-get update

Comment: PPA's are different from the regular/default repositories. `apt-get update` only gets the available packages, doesn't change the repos. I'll update with some directions that should restore your default repos

Comment: @akabhirav Did adding the keys work? Checked a couple and they're on both servers mentioned. Or any of the other ideas?