# ppa broke my repositorys

Tags: apt, ppa, repository

I am running Ubuntu 14.04. And added the ppa [`ppa:nathandyer/vocal-stable`](https://launchpad.net/~nathandyer/+archive/ubuntu/vocal-stable). After adding it, I runned `sudo apt-get update` and got the following error:

```
 Fetched 13,1 kB in 8s (1478 B/s)                                      
 Reading package lists... DoneW: GPG error: http://deb.playonlinux.com
 trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified
 because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY E0F72778C4676186W:
 GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following
 signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
 available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192W: GPG error:
 http://archive.canonical.com trusty Release: The following signatures
 couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:
 NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32W: GPG error:
 http://mega.nz ./ Release: The following signatures couldn't be
 verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
 B258DF0B4D70F67AW: GPG error: http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty
 Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the
 public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY
 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32W: GPG error: http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 trusty-updates Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified
 because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5
 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32W: GPG error: http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com
 trusty-backports Release: The following signatures couldn't be
 verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY
 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32W: GPG error:
 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com trusty-security Release: The following
 signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
 available: NO_PUBKEY 40976EAF437D05B5 NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32W: GPG
 error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following
 signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
 available: NO_PUBKEY 082CCEDF94558F59W: GPG error:
 https://private-ppa.launchpad.net quantal Release: The following
 signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not
 available: NO_PUBKEY E131728675254D99W: GPG error: https://repo.tox.im
 nightly Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because
 the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B111B5D7DF12B85
```

I downloaded [y-ppa manager](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/y-ppa-manager-0092-released-with-new.html) and runned all the fixes, as seen in the screenshot below, but no luck.

[image]

I also `purge` the `ppa:nathandyer/vocal-stable`, and also `locate` everything connected with that ppa, and `rm` them.

**Update from comment:**
My problem is already fixed. From someone outside of Ask Ubuntu. I asked him if I can post the steps to fixing this, here. Of course in quote format crediting him. Still waiting for reply!

Comment: "After adding it, I runned sudo apt-get update and got an error." What was te first error you get? " I downloaded y-ppa manager and runned all the fixes, but no luck." What fixes?

Comment: See nelaar answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys

Comment: @ElderGeek I tried most of the answers there. But, no luck!

Comment: So far none of those answers fixed my problem! :(

Comment: Why don't you remove the PPA which is conflicting.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, you tried nelaar answer (which had nothing to do with y-ppa) at the link I quoted and that failed? What was the error? Please [edit] your question to include that information in order to help us help you! Drop me a comment **when you have done so** and I'll take another look.

Comment: @ElderGeek the above error was the one I keep getting. **BUT**, my problem is already fixed. From someone outside of Ask Ubuntu. I asked him if I can post the steps to fixinf this, here.  Of course in quote format crediting him. Still waiting for reply!

Comment: @blade19899 you should be allowed to. Make sure to add it as an [answer], and reference where it was first posted.

Comment: @ElderGeek I will post it in the question before how to fix missing gpg keys question, because this is kinda the same problem, but different cause!

Comment: Here is is: http://askubuntu.com/a/612594/36315