# Cannot remove codeblocks using apt-get - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management, software-installation, dependencies, code-blocks

Whenever I try to run `sudo apt-get remove codeblocks` I am met with this message: 
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

```
codeblocks-contrib : Depends: libgamin0 but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libwxsmithlib0 (= 13.12-1) but 13.12-3 is to be installed
                      Depends: codeblocks (= 13.12-1) but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cppcheck but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cscope but it is not going to be installed
                      Recommends: cccc but it is not going to be installed
 codeblocks-dbg : Depends: codeblocks (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed
                  Depends: codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-3) but 13.12-1 is to be installed
 libwxsmithlib0 : Depends: libcodeblocks0 (= 13.12-3) but 13.12-1 is to be installed
                  Recommends: codeblocks-contrib (= 13.12-3) but 13.12-1 is to be installed
 libwxsmithlib0-dev : Depends: libwxsmithlib-dev (= 13.12-3) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I then try to use `sudo apt-get -f install`, there's a prompt to install some software then I'm met with this message and error:

```
Unpacking codeblocks-dev (13.12-3) over (13.12-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/include/codeblocks/externaldepsdlg.h', which is also in package codeblocks-headers 13.12-1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/codeblocks-dev_13.12-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any suggestions? I've tried sudo apt-get remove codeblocks, but i'm met with nearly the same unmet dependencies error as before.

The reason I am trying to remove codeblocks is that I am trying to install gnome-themes-standard, but I was met with a similar unmet dependencies error (same packages listed). I'm guessing that something with the apt-get may be corrupted: I recently dual-booted windows 10 and moved a few OS partitions around.

Solutions I have tried:

1. `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
2. Removing `codeblocks-contrib` and `libwxsmithlib0`
3. `sudo apt-get autoclean`
4. `sudo apt-get clean`

If anyone knows how to fix this, please help.

---

If anyone is curious, I did get these errors when I used `sudo apt-get update` while writing this

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://download.opensuse.org  Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5A7D1D38BEB6D886
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B70731143DD9F856
```

---

**EDIT**

So I was able to actually solve the GPG error with `http:\\ppa.launchpad.net` through [this](http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html) which is summarized here:

1. I copied the current pubkey that is output (B70731143DD9F856)
2. Searched the key in keyserver.ubuntu.com as a hexidecimal (bascially formatted with a 0x => `0xB70731143DD9F856`)
3. Pressed the pubkey link   Copied the entire textblock (includign the ---begin--- and    ---end--- lines)
4. Pasted it into a text editor, saved it as key1  Ran `sudo apt-key
   add key1` in key1's directory then received an `OK`

and when I reran `sudo apt-get install`, the error on ppa launchpad was gone, but the other GPG error persisted. Trying this method with the opensuse error does not work as a search in the Ubuntu keyserver turns up nothing

Comment: How did you install codeblocks? [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey) or [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys) question may help with the missing GPG keys.

Comment: It's honestly been a while since I installed it, it's likely that I installed it using apt-get because that's how I have with the majority of my software.

Comment: Also I think I am completely not able to install software because of this issue, when I tried to install y-ppa-manager, the temrinal returned the same message.

Answer (score 2):

While revisiting this error today, I came upon the solution proposed in [this forum post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2281477). It turns out that the issue is caused by the cross dependency between several of the codeblocks packages, so the entire install needs to be repaired using this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge codeblocks-contrib-dbg codeblocks-libwxcontrib0 codeblocks-dbg \
codeblocks-dev codeblocks codeblocks-headers libcodeblocks0  codeblocks-contrib \
codeblocks-contrib-common codeblocks-wxcontrib-headers codeblocks-wxcontrib-dev \
codeblocks-common libwxsmithlib0 libwxsmithlib0 libwxsmithlib0-dev
```

copied in as one line in the terminal. After processing, I could once again successfully install software.

Answer (score 0):

you should run this command:

```
sudo apt-get purge *codeblocks*
```