# Install Mongo 3.2 on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: mongodb

I want to install Mongo 3.2 on Ubuntu 15.10.

The official [mongodb site gives steps up to 14.04](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

On the other hand, using the [normal ppa from Ubuntu uses the 2.6](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/+source/mongodb) version (which is kinda way too back).

Comment: I'm fairly certain those instructions will work fine.

Comment: @Zacharee1 I tried the mongodb site instructions, couldn't find the ppa in ubuntu 15.10 repositories.

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/sgnn7/54146c8a13c8b5ca2201

Comment: I wish I understood how the script gets to install the 3.2 as I don't see anywhere in it which installs the 3.2. I don't already have the 3.2 installed. Currently, 2.6 is installed, but I want the 3.2 instead.

Comment: OK. Try adding the 14.04 repo as it is (don't change it to Vivid). Then run that script and see if you can start Mongo

Comment: Actually, does this work? http://www.liberiangeek.net/2015/06/how-to-install-mongodb-in-ubuntu-15-04-easily/

Comment: Thanks for the link. @Zacharee1 That gets me to install 3.0. I'm looking for 3.2

Comment: Change `"$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse"` to `"$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse"`

Comment: I did that, obviously, but got these: `W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/wily/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/wily/mongodb-org/3.2/multiverse/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found`

Comment: OK. Replace `sudo echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu "$(lsb_release -sc)"/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse"` with `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse"`.

Comment: @Zacharee1 Got 3.2 to install, but can't start. `mongod` complains of `/data/db` not found, and `mongo` complains of inability to connect. I guess its about time I run the script?

Comment: Yeah. Try it out

Comment: Nice! Glad it works

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Thanks to [@Zacharee1](https://askubuntu.com/users/274320/zacharee1), I got 3.2 of Mongo installed on Ubuntu 15.10. Below are the steps taken from [LiberianGeek](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2015/06/how-to-install-mongodb-in-ubuntu-15-04-easily/) (changed just the version to match 3.2)

**Add Key**

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

**Add Sources List**

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.2 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

**Update your sources**

```
sudo apt-get update
```

**Install `mongodb-org`**

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

**Check if working**

```
sudo systemctl status mongod
```

**If not working**

```
sudo reboot
```

**If still not working**

- Run this script: https://gist.github.com/sgnn7/54146c8a13c8b5ca2201

At the time of writing this, I had Mongo 3.2.1.

[image: Working example. Mongo 3.2.1 on Ubuntu 15.10]

Comment: The key has expired and will give the user a "KEYEXPIRED" error. Use [the command in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46737148/453331) to fix all expired keys in the system.

Answer (score 9):

Following the above steps, I got a `public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY` error

In case this happens to anyone else, I resolved it with:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv EA312927
```

Comment: That's surprising though to me, 'cause I tried the apt-key from my answer, and it still exists.

Comment: I had the same issue, I did what @adam suggested, it worked. Thanks guys!

Comment: I also had this issue, but what worked was adding the key referenced in the error message (e.g. http://askubuntu.com/a/141088/430924)

Answer (score 4):

For Mongo v3.0 and before you should use this key:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

For Mongo v3.2 the key has an update:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv EA312927
```

https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.2/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/