# sudo apt-get update error in 14.04 LTS

Tags: 14.04, updates

I get this error when I run the above command.

```
W: GPG error: http://packages.ros.org trusty InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 5523BAEEB01FA116
W: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-i386/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I tried the methods posted in the forums but the problem isn't solved.
The details about my laptop are as follows:

```
kv@kv:~$ uname -a
Linux kv 3.19.0-49-generic #55~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 22 11:24:31 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Me too. Have been searching  on this all day. As soon as updater gets to the "Requires installation of untrusted packages" (why? Might be related to [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/03/fix-failed-to-fetch-google-chrome_3.html) in my case), Updater closes down with no updates having been made. I've been investigating [a fix](http://askubuntu.com/q/78951/38585), but no joy yet.

Comment: Please find the solution here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys/136735#136735

Comment: And for the line about google chrome, look at this question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/724093/no-more-updates-for-google-chrome-apt-get-update-error

Comment: @monitor35 I applied that "fix" earlier today - did nothing.

Comment: @ByteCommander - Thanks! Using [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/386003/38585) fixed it. I already had `y-ppa-manager` on my system, so very fast solution.

Comment: @monitor35 - I got the same error message

Comment: This worked for me for fixing the NO_PUBKEY error
http://opensourceforgeeks.blogspot.in/2013/04/w-gpg-error-httpppalaunchpadnet-precise.html