# How can you verify if a repository key is trustworthy?

Tags: apt, security

Yesterday when trying to update a server, we got a BADSIG error - the repository was au.archive.ubuntu.com

After a bit of research, we found that we had to reimport the key that is listed in the error message - but I'm wondering how do we know that new key is trustworthy?

[How to fix missing GPG keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys)

http://naveenubuntu.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/fixing-gpg-keys-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Remember, there is also http://security.stackexchange.com

Comment: As what the user said above, I'd recommend looking around on security.stackexchange.com, they're some really smart folks over there, and keep browsing this forum as well, I know this question has been asked elsewhere I just can't seem to find the link.