# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available

Tags: 16.04, apt, pgp

***Before marking this as duplicate, please read the whole question. I've tried all the suggestions in all the related questions I could find, without any success.***

I get errors about missing keys for **all** repos when doing `sudo apt update`. Running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

```
Get:14 url xenial InRelease [4 731 B]
Err:14 url InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because
  the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY KEY
```

Deleting and adding the keys manually has no effect at all.

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com KEY1 KEY2 ...`

Another related problem that I see is that the **Software and Updates** app has no entries in the **Authentication** tab. Which leads me to believe it's an issue related to permissions.

[image]

I've checked permissions and compared with what I see is normal online, but can't see anything wrong.

```
drw-rw-r--   7 root root  4096 mars  28 09:01 .
drwxr-xr-x 158 root root 12288 mars  28 09:08 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 mars  28 09:08 apt.conf.d
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 okt.   5  2015 preferences.d
-rw-r--r--   1 root root   653 feb.   7 11:22 sources.list
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  3100 okt.  12 09:57 sources.list.bak
drw-r--r--   2 root root  4096 feb.   7 11:23 sources.list.d
drw-r--r--   2 root root  4096 feb.   1 09:55 sources.list.d.bak
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root  2902 april 22  2016 sources.list.distUpgrade
-rw-rw-r--   1 root root   653 feb.   7 11:22 sources.list.save
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 29811 mars  28 09:01 trusted.gpg
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 28668 mars  28 09:01 trusted.gpg~
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 feb.   7 11:22 trusted.gpg.d
```

I'm stuck now, so any suggestions apart from reinstalling Ubuntu from scratch will be highly appreciated :)

Comment: can you try `sudo chmod 644 sources.list`?

Comment: @Yaron, tried that now, but no change, unfortunately. Still wrong key on all repos.

Adding the reported missing keys gives an "unchange count"  of the same as keys _I try to update. They are there, but apt just cant use them when fetching updates.

Comment: did you get key-id after the message *  the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY KEY*?

Comment: can you please confirm that the answers in this [Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys) didn't solve your problem?

Comment: I can confirm that the suggested solution does not resolve the issue, as also stated in the Q from day one :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there is no resolution to this problem, so unfortunately the only valid solution know atm. is to **re-install Ubuntu from scratch**.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com PUT_KEY_HERE
```

You would find the key in the error message like this:

```bash
....NO_PUBKEY KEY_IS_HERE
```

That was because, you need to authenticate it as a trusted site and you need a signing key. This command will create it.

Comment: As I wrote in the question, I tried this, but it does not help. It says 0 keys changed. So they are clearly there.

Comment: Sorry, I missed what you wrote there. This solved for me. I can't tell what else do you need, wish I could help. I was seeing the exact same error message.