# Adding new key still throws error how to remove sub apt-key

Tags: apt, repository, gnupg

Installing the *yarn package manager* from its [instruction](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install#debian-stable) I did add its key and some weeks ago the key was expired. so I did the `apt-key add` again. but still on `sudo apt update` I get the warning:

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F77679369475BAA
W: Failed to fetch https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F77679369475BAA
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

`sudo apt-key list` shows that there are two keys where one is expired

```
    pub   rsa4096 2016-10-05 [SC]
      72EC F46A 56B4 AD39 **** **** **** **** **** ****
    uid           [ unknown] Yarn Packaging <yarn@dan.cx>
    sub   rsa4096 2016-10-05 [E]
    sub   rsa4096 2019-01-02 [S] [expires: 2020-02-02]
```

How can I remove only the expired one?

Answer (score 0):

Hy try this issue here, renewing the key to add the missing key mentioned in the error message.

[How to fix missing GPG keys?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/127326/how-to-fix-missing-gpg-keys)

Answer (score 0):

It's just the signing key changed if you still getting this error even in newer releases you should just add it manually via
To add the latest key:

```
wget -qO - https://raw.githubusercontent.com/yarnpkg/releases/gh-pages/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

or

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```