# add-apt-repository command is suddenly very slow

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, ppa, add-apt-repository

There were no issues before, but today I started my computer and I removed the unstable OIBAF graphics drivers and tried to add stable OIBAF graphics PPA. I left for about 15 minutes and when I came back the terminal was stuck at the initial command without any output. It looked like this:

[image]

I thought this was an internet issue, but it wasn't. Then I canceled adding the PPA and tried to install it again but had the same issue (the `apt-add-repository` command does works but takes a lot of time to show any output. Everything was fine before --it took less than a minute to complete-- but now it takes more than 15 minutes).

I've also tried adding different PPAs but had the same issue.

My kernel version is 4.20.0

I've also built a kernel installed and removed but then there was no ppa related issue.

EDIT: There's more delay when I cancel the command with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: I'd suggest trying again in a few hours - internet connection issues may not be limited to your computer/network, and it may be that some system between your computer and the PPA servers is overloaded

Comment: @Charles Green No it is not internet issue at all. My laptop with mint connected to same network works fine. Also my computer is new so no problem of ports/wifi etc. it is just all repositories are slow.

Comment: @pomsky I'd add a `traceroute` from me to launchpad (8 hops), but in comments that's a painful experience.

Comment: I solved problem by deleting repositories with missing gpg keys

Comment: @SaurabhSingh how exactly did you do that? I am having the same problem and would like to solve that. Could you share commands to delete repos with missing gpg keys?

Comment: @matt525252 `sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:<ppa to remove>` or edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`.You have to find repositoriy with missing keys though. Also you can add missing keys, follow this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/141088/898816

Comment: Thank you for reply. How exactly can I find which one has a missing gpg key?

Comment: @matt525252 When you do `apt update` there should be some warnings like `W: GPG error: <repository>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue, it was due to other unsigned repository I added to my system because of this there is a lot of delay in adding PPAs. Simply remove those unsigned PPAs and problem will be solved.

Comment: Could you please share how did you fix it?

Answer (score 7):

I came here for the same reason that,

`apt-add-repository` command does works but takes a lot of time to show any output -- now it takes more than 15 minutes.

and I found the root cause and solution from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/500286/

> It seems to be a DNS routing issue.

*temporarily* disabled IPv6 fixed the problem:

`sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

Answer (score 0):

my problem was ip6tables input policy set to DROP without allowing local traffic. these need to be there:

```
ip6tables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

after adding rules the system resolved all repositories.

btw., i found that `strace` command often output exact address system hang trying to resolve, making this easier to debug.